# Apache Camel throwing NoSuchEndPointException

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am unable to read the file from a particular folder
this is my code for routebuilder

```
@Component("RequestFileRouteBuilder")
public class RequestFileRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder{
       @Override
       public void configure() throws Exception{
              from("file:files/input")
             .routeId("Myroute")
             .process(Myprocessor);//processes the file input
       }
}
```

Due to security violation I cannot share the entire pom.xml file which we are using in our project
But I have included camel-file,camel-spring,camel-bean,camel-core.

the error which I am getting after running my application is as below

Caused by : org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndPointException : No endpoint cpould be found for : file://files/input, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.

I actually added camel-file dependency later after going through this site
https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/file-component.html

Where can I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of code seems to be working fine. Below is the code snippet which is working fine in my machine.

```
@Component("requestFileRouteBuilder")
public class RequestFileRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception{
    from("file:C:/files/input/")
            .routeId("RequestFileRouteId")
            .process(exchange -> {log.info(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));});
}}
```

Below are the logs from application

```
2023-04-02 12:08:59.987  INFO 7192 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   :     Started RequestFileRouteId (file://C:/files/input/)

2023-04-02 12:08:59.987  INFO 7192 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.14.0 (camel-1) started in 420ms (build:83ms init:313ms start:24ms)
2023-04-02 12:08:59.994  INFO 7192 --- [           main] com.example.Application                  : Started Application in 6.136 seconds (JVM running for 7.67)
2023-04-02 12:09:16.841  INFO 7192 --- [C:/files/input/] c.example.route.RequestFileRouteBuilder  : Test Message
```

Below might be the issue that I can think of:

1. Are you passing full path to the input directory?
2. Have you included below dependencies in your pom xml?

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   ```

Also, you need to check whether the spring boot version and camel version you are using are compatible with each other or not.

Comment: I changed the spring boot version and it worked. Great Thanks!